# Is it possible to have workers running "virtually" 24h/7 in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have real time data incoming and I need to process it 24h/7, but:

**a)** Heroku will restart Dynos once a day.

**b)** Heroku will restart Dynos when code is updated.

Point **a**, can be more or less handled by having multiple dynos, if one restarts, the other is still there.

But for point **b**, I don't see how I can handle it. If all dynos restart for an update, I'll lose data until they are up again.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can enable [preboot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot) on your dynos.

> Preboot changes the standard dyno start behavior for web dynos. Instead of stopping the existing set of web dynos before starting the new ones, preboot ensures that the new web dynos are started (and receive traffic) before the existing ones are terminated. This can contribute to zero downtime deployments.
>
> ```
> heroku features:enable preboot -a <myapp>
> ```

Do read the entire docs - there are some important considerations / caveats to be mindful of, like the fact that deployments will now take several minutes to switch to the newer set of dynos.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Lots of caveats indeed. Also it does not work for workers, only web processes. A pity, Heroku is quite good to start a project but seems to be a showstopper for real time stuff.

Comment: @Kev Well, the incoming data is presumably coming to the web workers initially. Have them add to a queue, so the workers being down for a minute doesn't break anything.